# Commerce product variation with different variations

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm still pretty new to Drupal Commerce so I don't know if it's possible to group different variations under a product variation. This may sound weird, so here is an example of a grouped product variation.

[image: Table structure]

As you can see the different product types have common values. The networking one has all values. So this is what I would like to achieve:

- Create one product variation called `transmission`
- Have the option to select the product type

  - The selection you made in the product type column will change the values you need to fill in.

Is this possible? Or would there be an other recommended solution to group like this. I would like to prevent that I have to create variations for each product type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you can create a **Type** field on the product and then have allowed values for Fiber, UTP or other. If you create these as a Taxonomy field, then they can be used to categorize other products or services with that same term.

You can create all of the fields and then use custom code to alter the [form states](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7) to require/hide/show/etc. various fields on the form. All of the fields will exist, but only some of them might be shown. When you create your template for the product, you'll just need to ensure that you theme it properly.